# How do you print the current line count in sed while inside a substitution command?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Using `sed` I would like to process a file by simply adding the current line count at the end of each row.

For example, given `textfile.txt`, containing:

```
$ cat textfile.txt
word
letters
music
```

Becomes:

```
$ sed '<magic sed commands>' textfile.txt
word    line1
letters line2
music   line3
```

In `awk`, for example, I can do this as follows:

```
$ awk '{print $1"\tline"NR;}' textfile.txt
word    line1
letters line2
music   line3
```

I've tried playing with `=` in sed, but it doesn't get honored inside a substitution `'s///'` block, i.e. `'s///; ='` works, but `'s//=/'` obviously doesn't (the `=` is interpreted literally).

Comment: Why do you need it in sed, when you can do it in awk?

Comment: @choroba So I would like to know how it's done in more than one way? For instance, I can do it in `bash`, `python`, `C`, etc., but would like to know if it can be done (and how) with sed.

Comment: See [Numbering Lines](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#cat-_002dn). Keep in mind you should still not do this in `sed` if you have any other option (and you do, usually). There are other counting examples on the same page.

Comment: You can also ask **How to do maths in sed**? Point is always use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -n 'p;=' file | sed 'N;s/\n/\tline/'
```

Output:

```
word    line1
letters line2
music   line3
```

Comment: For OS X's (BSD) sed, which is what I'm running this test on, one needs to insert a literal `<TAB>` character, '\t' doesn't work even when quoted strongly:  

`$ sed -n 'p;=' file | sed "N;s/\n/$(printf '\t')line/" # bash-specific`

or:  

`$ sed -n 'p;=' file | sed 'N;s/\n/[CTRL+V, <TAB>]line/' # still bash-specific`

Comment: You can try this with bash: `sed -n 'p;=' file | sed "N;s/\n/"$'\t'"line/"`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -n '' YourFile | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\):\(.*\)/\2 line \1/'
```

because sed does not allow easily the task in 1 sed action script, i number line with grep and sed after.
It's possible to number in sed (`=` could not help because it send the info to output and not to the working buffer, so no action on it) but a very heavy action where other tools do it finger in the noose (like awk as quick alternative here after)

```
awk '{print $0 " line " NR}' YourFile
```